# error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c, include

I get the error:

```
ndefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_setVal", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

I looked up other posts but nothing seems so solve the problem.
I think that I used include properly.

main.c:

```
#include "game.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
setVal(board, 1, 0, 6);
}
```

game.h:

```
#ifndef GAME_H_
#define GAME_H_

bool SetVal(Board* board, int row, int col, int value);

#endif
```

game.c:

```cpp
#include "game.h"

bool SetVal(Board* board, int row, int col, int value){
// code in here
}
```

What can be cause of the error?
Thank you.

Comment: What command are you using to compile?

Comment: Where is `board` defined in `main.c`?

Comment: Where is `Board` defined?

Comment: Please read compiler warnings. This would warn you for implicit function declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typo:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SetVal(board, 1, 0, 6);
//  ^
}
```

Comment: When answers are as simple as this, please post as a comment instead. It makes it easier to remove the question later.

Comment: @klutt Why would the question be removed later?

Comment: @trojanfoe Because questions where the problem is a simple typo in general is of no use to future readers. This question is likely to be closed for "simple typographical error"

Comment: @klutt Well I think referencing a missing symbol because of mis-spelling is of use to future readers, so I am happy if the question remains.